# Angular + nginx. Ошибка 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: nginx

Nginx кидает ошибку 500. Указываю путь до файла index.html в папке dist (папка билда ангуляром)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.server;
        root /home/ilya/frontend/dist;
        location / {
            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```